# Lucene : Find result with single word search

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to find a match using one word as a query but it can't seem to find it.  I am using standard analyzer but can't find the exact result.

My indexed document is:

```
Document d = new Document();
d.add(new StringField("content","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
```

If I use a WildCard Query:

```
Term term = new Term("content","The*");
Query q = new WildcardQuery(term);
```

It will return the content: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

If I use a TermQuery :

```
Term term = new Term("content","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
Query q = new TermQuery(term);
```

It will return the content: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Now, I want to use "fox" as my new term

```
Term term= new Term("content","fox");
```

But I don't know which is the right query to use, or how to do it.  I already tried QueryParser, TermQuery, and MultiPhrase but still no luck.

Any help will do or guide.  Or just a simple query which I can use as a guide.  I have read a lot of tutorials but can't find the right one.  I am using lucene 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't read Javadoc for `StringField` which says:

> <..> the entire String value is indexed as a single token <..>

Just use `TextField` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, it seems that it would be better to tokenize the whole string:

```
Document doc = new Document(); 

doc.Add(new Field("Contents", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
```

This should enable you to search for individual terms as well.